# Installation problem

Tags: qgis, installation

When I executed the QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.28.10-1.msi, it showed the image like the picture.I chose the “Repair “,but it also showed the same picture.Even I chose the ”Remove” and reinstalled, it also showed this.

[image]

Comment: I had a problem that QGIS was very slow and even though I uninstalled it some files remained and kept causing problems. So after the uninstall, I searched the drive for all folders and files with either qgis or osgeo in the name and deleted them manually. Then reinstalled OsGeo. I dont know if might help you?